# Bash script for copying only modified files

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, diff

I have a very large base dir called proj_base containing humongous amount of files and directories.

Mostly every day I create a `proj_base_ndate` and copy contents previous day folder `proj_base_n-1date`, and so forth.

For obvious memory limitations I want to change my foolish way of working. Now I want to **copy the folder blindly, edit as required, and then in the end like to use `diff` to compare** (suppose `base_dir/f1/file1` = `yesterday.c`, `base_dir/f2/file1`= `today.c`), **iteratively for all the files**, and the **non modified files, should be replaced by symlinks**(like for instance `today.c` replaced by symlink of `yesterday.c` if no change in `today.c`), leaving the remaining files copied.

I found out there might be a problem (might be many) in this approach, as for each unmodified file its a symlink to previous file forming a chain of symlinks, so if it happened to change; the root would get changed affecting all the past files, so can it be avoided?

And also any feasible ways for adding or deleting files?

I hope may be this way I would be able to save some space, but any other ways or utilities are also welcomed.

Till now I am able to use

```
diff -s
```

to check if they are identical or not, but I'm not getting how to make it iterative in a loop in a bash script, with the corner cases.

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe consider using overlayfs instead of copying the old folder to the new everyday? If you mount the "new" folder over the "old" one via overlayfs, all changed files will be written only to "new" folder and unchanged files won't be touched. Check: https://blog.programster.org/overlayfs

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to roll your own version control / revision control system - I would suggest checking out one of the many pre-exisiting tools instead